# Reaching the end of the value pool for autogenerated (IDENTITY) fields

Tags: database, auto-increment

Most database support `autogenerate` for an INT field, mostly used as the key for that table. It sometimes is set named `id` for short.

how much time before the program lets say c# int and the database `INT` value no longer support each other, or how long before the `INT` value is used up, or how large is this auto generated id field for a database, lets say sqlite?

When you try to insert a new record, and the data base auto generated row id is used up, what happens; no more insert?

thanks

[EDIT]

Do you look at the ID values of your tables once in a while?

Most people don't know that if for some reason you app does alot of insert and delete, then a new `ID` value is generated each time you insert. is seems that databases does not reuse deleted `ID`, so in that case a database with just `1000` records can use up that value if the app does alot of insert and deleteing!!!

The reason i asked this question is this, normally in apps you frequently make use of the `ID` value, to keep track of records; i do always.

lest say i did somthing like this

```
int record_id= reader("id").value;
```

when will i get an overflow error?
is the database `INT` the same as `int` in all programing environment?

Comment: 1st paragraph I understood, 2nd and 3rd not very much.

Comment: I feel like it belongs to SO. A purely technical question.

Comment: Please clarify the platform question, apparently your original question referenced SQLlite specifically. Platform does matter here as implementation details of this type differ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about sqlite but for the SQL Server the maximum values look like this:

```
max int (32 bit) = 2,147,483,647
max bigint (64 bit) = 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
```

If at some point you've used up the value range then an attempt to insert a new record will fail. It will say the following:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting IDENTITY to data type int. Arithmetic overflow occurred.

Again, have no idea about sqlite but in SQL Server the failed transactions will also consume a value from the pool. If you attempt an insert and the containing transaction is rolled back then the generated IDENTITY value will not be returned to the pool. If you have transactions failing regularly then that will also waste a certain ( though very small) percentage of the values.

Most likely sqlite works in a similar way.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that failing transactions will consume available values.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum size for an INT in SQLite is 8-bytes, which is a very, very big number. I find it hard to imagine an application which used SQLite where you could actually "run out" of INTs. You would have to be running some very large data-warehousing system for this to happen, which you are not going to be doing with SQLite. So don't worry!

Comment: According to http://www.sqlite.org/datatypes.html SQLite uses signed 32-bit integers, so you run out around 2 billion.  Still difficult to do, but a lot easier than 8-byte integers (aka 64-bit integers) would have done.

Comment: @Jeremy He did say it - he must have edited the question inside the grace period. Note both me and DA thought he said it.